# Web2py SQLFORM.grid with executesql

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

I am making a web2py application and I have my two mysql tables defined in my models db.py file:

```
db.define_table('table1',
    Field('id','integer'),
    Field('name','string'),
    migrate=False)

db.define_table('table2',
    Field('id','integer'),
    Field('name','string'),
    migrate=False)
```

I want my application to return a union of these tables:

```
data=db.executesql('SELECT * FROM table1 union select * from table2;')
```

in a SQLFORM.grid but apparently

```
form=SQLFORM.grid(data, create=False, deletable=False, editable=False, maxtextlength=100, paginate=10)
```

is not the way to go.

Can somebody help me please? It must be really simple but I'm having trouble finding the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grid is designed to take a table or query, so you cannot pass a `Rows` object or arbitrary SQL. The best approach would be to create a view in the database and create a new DAL model definition associated with that view (be sure to set `migrate=False`, as you don't want the DAL to attempt to create a table with the name of the view). Then you can pass the view model to the grid:

```
db.define_table('t1_t2_union_view',
    Field('id','integer'),
    Field('name','string'),
    migrate=False)

grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.t1_t2_union_view, ...)
```

The above works because web2py will treat the model of the database view like any other database table, issuing a query to select all of its records. There is no need for `executesql` in this case because the union of the tables is handled in the database by the view.

Actually, you can simplify the table definition to:

```
db.define_table('t1_t2_union_view', db.table1, migrate=False)
```

When you pass an existing table to `.define_table()`, you get a new table with the same field defintions as the original, which is what we want here.

If creating separate views for each possible union is not feasible, a possible alternative would be to retrieve the data via `executesql` and then iterate through the records, inserting each one into an in-memory SQLite database table, which could then be passed to the grid:

```
union_tables = ('table1', 'table2')
temp_db = DAL('sqlite:memory')
union_table = temp_db.define_table('union_table', db[union_tables[0]])

records = db.executesql(sql, as_dict=True)
for record in records:
    union_table.insert(**union_table._filter_fields(record))

grid = SQLFORM.grid(union_table, create=False, editable=False, deletable=False)
```

Setting `as_dict=True` results in a list of dictionaries being returned, which makes it easier to do the inserts, as the keys of the dictionaries are the field names needed for the inserts.

Note, this method is somewhat inefficient, so you would have to test it to see how it performs with your workload.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. So even if i do this how do I populate the grid each time with the union created by executesql? I am asking that because my example is simplified and I want to make different unions for different tables each time.

Comment: With this solution, you are no longer using `executesql`. Instead, you are defining a view directly in the database that generates the union. Then define a model in web2py for that view. web2py doesn't know the difference between a view and a regular table, so it will query the view just as it would a table. Of course, you will have to make a different database view for each possible union. If there are too many possibilities to make that practical, you should probably consider something like [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) rather than the web2py grid.

Comment: I see.. so basically it can't be done the way I want it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: One possible hack would be to retrieve the data via `executesql` and then iterate through the records, inserting each one into an in-memory SQLite database table. I added this solution to the answer.